# How to include currency format in sum datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this datatable, I want to sum the column and add the result with currency format in the footer . The sum is working fine but I can't figure out how to add the curency format in the totals.
Can you help me please?

```
  footerCallback: function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api();
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    api.column(5).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
                        return a + b;
                    }, 0)
                );
                $(api.column(6).footer()).html(
                    api.column(6).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
                       return  a + b;
                    }, 0)
                );
                 $(api.column(7).footer()).html(
                    api.column(7).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
                        return  a + b;
                    }, 0)
                );
                var col8 = $(api.column(8).footer()).html(
                    api.column(8).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
                    return a + b; 
                    }, 0)
               );   
               
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes to display the column sums as currency amounts:

1. Assign the `reduce` function to a separate variable.
2. Use the JavaScript `Intl.NumberFormat()` function to format the sum as a currency.
3. (Optional step) Create a common function for each column, to avoid repeating the same code multiple times.

Steps 1 and 2 would look as follows for a single column:

```js
footerCallback: function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
  var api = this.api();
  var sum = api.column(1).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
  var amount = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).format(sum);
  $(api.column(1).footer()).html(amount);
}
```

You can obviously change the `USD` currency code to whatever currency format you prefer.

For step 3, there are different approaches.

Here is one approach: We start with an array containing the column indexes where we want to display a sum. In my case this is `[1, 2]`.  Each value is passed to a function `doSum()`:

```js
var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "amount_a": 1,
      "amount_b": 12.34
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "amount_a": 3,
      "amount_b": 456.78
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "amount_a": 5,
      "amount_b": 678.90
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "amount_a": 2,
      "amount_b": 32.21
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "amount_a": 3,
      "amount_b": 1.12
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "amount_a": 1,
      "amount_b": 2.23
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "amount_a": 4,
      "amount_b": 3.34
    }
  ];
 
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { title: "ID", data: "id" },
      { title: "Amount A", data: "amount_a" },
      { title: "Amount B", data: "amount_b" }
    ],

    footerCallback: function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
      var api = this.api();
      [1, 2].forEach( function( colIdx ) {
        doSum( api.column(colIdx) );
      } );
    }

  } );

  function doSum(col) {
    var sum = col.data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
    var amount = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}).format(sum);
    $(col.footer()).html(amount);
  }
  
} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <tfoot>
            <th style="text-align: right;">Totals:</th><th></th><th></th>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Have you taken the site [tour]? If you have not, I highly recommend it.